# Worst case examples of non-differentiability of the Riemannian distance function

Tags: derivatives, riemannian-geometry

Let $g$ be a $C^\infty$ Riemannian metric on the plane, and let $p$ be a point on the plane. Let $X$ be the set of points $x$ at which the Riemannian distance $d(p,x)$ is not differentiable. How bad can $X$ be? Rademacher proved that a Lipschitz function is differentiable almost everywhere. So $X$ has to have measure zero. Can $\overline X$, the closure of $X$, have non-empty interior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the closure of $X$ has locally finite $1$-dimensional measure. Indeed, the set of non-differentiability points is contained in the [cut locus](https://mathoverflow.net/q/62025) of $p$, which is a closed set. It was proved by Hebda and Itoh that the intersection of cut locus with every compact set has finite $1$-dimensional measure. See

1. Hebda, James J. *Metric structure of cut loci in surfaces and Ambrose's problem*. J. Differential Geom. 40 (1994), no. 3, 621–642.
2. Itoh, Jin-ichi. *The length of a cut locus on a surface and Ambrose's problem*. J. Differential Geom. 43 (1996), no. 3, 642–651.

Both papers (and other related literature) are referenced in the paper [The Lipschitz continuity of the distance function to the cut locus](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-01/S0002-9947-00-02564-2/) by  Itoh and  Tanaka, where the result is extended to arbitrary dimensions, and to cut locus of a submanifold (which could be a point). This paper is in free access.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think this question is more suitable for www.mathoverflow.net

I will consider the general setting of a Riemannian manifold $M$ (of arbitrary dimension and topology). Define the non-smoothness set $N(p)$ set of the distance function $d(p, x)$ (with fixed $p$), the cut-locus $C(p)$ of the point $p$ and the set $NU(p)$ consisting of points $q\in M$ such that the minimizing geodesic segment connecting $p$ to $q$ is non-unique. It is clear that
$$
N(p)\subset NU(p). 
$$
Quite a bit is known about $C(p)$, some of the results are summarized in Berger's book "Riemannian Geometry During the Second Half of the Twentieth Century" (page 113). In particular, it is known that 
$$
C(p)= \overline{NU(p)}. 
$$
From this, it is easy to see that $N(p)$ is contained in a closed set of zero measure and, hence, the answer to your question is negative. Berger further cites a result by Gluck and Singer that $C(p)$ can, in general, be non-triangulable.