# Is a maximal open simply connected subset $U$ of a manifold $M$, necessarily dense?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

There is a short argument using Zorn's lemma and the compactness of $[0,1]$, that shows every manifold must have maximal open simply connected subspaces.

However, I am wondering if it is necessarily the case that these subspaces are dense. It seems quite obvious to me that they must be dense, but am having some difficulty with the proof. Is this true, or do I lack the imagination to come up with a counterexample?

As Nate pointed out, I should have required the manifold to be connected.

Comment: At a minimum, you want to assume $M$ is connected, right?

Comment: yes of course, sorry I don't often think about non-connected manifolds.

Comment: Can you do something like that? Assume not, then there is $p$ not in $U$ and $p\in V$ so that $U\cap V = \emptyset$. Assume also that $V$ is a ball and draw a curve from the boundary of $V$ to the boundary of $U$ (choose it so that it is "closest"). Thinken this curve a little bit to give an open set $W$. Then $U' = V \cup W\cup U$ is open simply connected.

Comment: @JohnMa That was what I tried originally, however I run into issues, that I couldn't seem to fix. For instance, say that there is a 'slit' cut out of the open meaning some line segment removed from the boundary. How do we know that you don't say accidentally, close up part (but not all) of the slit and end up with something that is not simply connected.  Now it seems these "slits" can't crop up in these maximal open sets, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Comment: How exactly do you make Zorn work?  Given a chain of simply connected opens, the natural thing to try for their upper bound is the union, but I don't see why the union is necessarily simply connected.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Given an increasing sequence of  subspaces $U_1 \subset U_2 \subset \dots$, call their union $U$. If every compact subset of $U$ is contained in some $U_i$ then $\lim \pi_1(U_i) = \pi_1(U)$. Indeed this holds for all homotopy groups or homology groups. Proof: there is a canonical map from the left side of that equality to the right side. Surjectivity: any loop in $U$ lies in some $U_i$ by assumption. Injectivity: if a loop in $U_i$ was null-homotopic in $U$, that null-homotopy would lie in some $U_j \supset U_i$, by the same compactness assumption, which is true for $U_i$ open.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Given a map $S^1\to M$ the image is compact so as it is covered by the chain it is covered by some element in the chain, and that element in the chain must be simply-connected by assumption.

Comment: @PVAL:  That's short and simple.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the "manifold" condition would be completely essential if it's true, even very nice spaces (manifold with a single singularity) wouldn't work: look at $S^1 \vee [0,1]$, then $S^1$ minus the point at which $[0,1]$ is attached is a maximal simply connected open subset which isn't dense (I've been pulling my hair out thinking about this problem for hours and the only conclusion I've reached is that I've no idea if it's true).

Comment: It feels like this result should be implied by the fact that a punctured connected manifold of dimension $n$ deformation retracts onto an embedded $(n-1)$-dimensional CW-complex. (I think that's true anyway, probably from homological considerations.)

Answer (score 8):

The following answers a weaker form of your question, namely, *is it true that every connected topological manifold contains an open dense simply-connected subset*? The answer to this question is positive and even more is true:

**Theorem.** Every connected topological $n$-manifold contains an open dense subset homeomorphic to $R^n$.

This follows from a theorem by R.Berlanga "A mapping theorem for topological sigma-compact manifolds", Compositio Math, 1987, vol. 63, 209-216.

Berlanga's theorem generalized an earlier work by M.Brown, who proved the same theorem for compact topological manifolds. (The case of triangulated manifolds is easy but serves as a guideline for proofs in the topological category.)

Berlanga's theorem does not answer, however, the question if **every** maximal simply-connected open subset is dense in $M$.