# How many ways can we compactify $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, compact-manifolds, compactification

Below are two different ways we can compactify $\mathbb{C}$:

The first is "adding a point at infinity", the second is "adding a disc at infinity".

[image]

Intuitively, it looks like these are the only two ways we can compactify $\mathbb{C}$. (I declare that any other "disc" compactification is equivalent to the one I've drawn - although I'm not sure what the appropriate type of "equivalence" is.) Are there other non-trivial ways to compactify $\mathbb{C}$? Maybe there are other compactifications if we don't require it to be conformal?

Otherwise, are there nontrivial ways to compactify $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: There's the Stone-Cech compactification...

Comment: If by compactification you mean putting $\mathbb C$ inside a compact set, that can be a lot of them..

Comment: Moebius Strip, Torus, Klein Bottle, Annulus, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every open connected $k$-dimensional manifold $M$ contains an open and dense subset homeomorphic to $R^k$. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419249/is-a-maximal-open-simply-connected-subset-u-of-a-manifold-m-necessarily-den/1529732#1529732).

Hence, every compact connected $2n$-dimensional manifold is homeomorphic to a compactification of ${\mathbb C}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a space $C$ a *[compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics))* of $C$ is a compact space $X$ that contains a homeomorphic copy of $C$ as a dense subset. A space can have many different compactifications, e.g. we have $S^1$ as one-point compactification and $[{-1},1]$ as two-point compactification of ${\mathbb R}$, whereby we of course write ${\mathbb R}\cup\{\infty\}$, resp., ${\mathbb R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ for these concepts.

The following is an example where we compactify ${\mathbb C}$ by adding a circle: The map
$$f:\quad{\mathbb C}\to D, \qquad z\mapsto{z\over 1+|z|}$$
is a homeomorphism of ${\mathbb C}$ with the unit disc $D\subset{\mathbb C}$. It follows that $\bar D$ can be considered as a compactification of ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: The OP identifies two compactifications of C and asks if there are any others. This answer just repeats those two.

Comment: @DavidHartley: To me a $2$-disc and a $1$-sphere are different. Apart from that, I had the impression that the OP didn't have the general idea of a compactification. But never mind.