# Manifold with "Distinct" Charts

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm looking for an example of a connected manifold $M$ (ideally a closed manifold) that requires "distinct" charts.

By requiring distinct charts I mean that there is no single coordinate chart $(U, \phi)$ on $M$ where $U$ is simply connected and dense in $M$.

I thought it would be easy to give a concrete example, but I'm struggling to come up with one. For example, the sphere $S^2$ does not work because there is the chart $(S^2 \setminus \{N \}, \phi)$ where $N$ is the north pole, and $\phi$ is the stereographic projection from the north pole.

My next idea was to consider a surface of genus $2$, but I didn't have a way of proving that such a chart didn't exist.

Comment: Are your charts allowed to be non-simply connected?

Comment: Disconnected manifolds give many trivial examples.

Comment: I think every connected closed manifold ought to have such a chart, maybe under some mild additional hypotheses. This would follow if they had CW complex structures, since I think it's then known that they ought to have CW complex structures with one cell of top dimension, which is the desired dense chart. This ought to at least be provable in the smooth case using Morse theory but I don't know about the non-smooth case.

Comment: I added the simply connected hypothesis. Also, yes, I am looking for connected manifolds. I should have specified.

Comment: Every connected manifold admits such a chart. This was asked before.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419249/is-a-maximal-open-simply-connected-subset-u-of-a-manifold-m-necessarily-den/1529732#1529732 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322027/how-much-of-an-n-dimensional-manifold-can-we-embed-into-mathbbrn/677158#677158

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you. I checked for other answers but didn't find them. Those do answer my question so I'm fine with a vote to close.