Can we find a zero measure set C such that for a complete Riemannian manifold M, the complement M\C is contained in a coordinate chart?
For a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, if we can always find a Zero measure set $C$ such that $M \backslash{} C$ is contained in a coordinate chart, the integration on $M$ will reduce to a multiple integral. Is this correct? If so, how do we prove the existence of such a set $C$?
The motivation for pondering this question lies in the fact that surface integrals in Euclidean space often involve similar operations, but proving it in that case can be challenging. Perhaps it is easier to prove for Riemannian manifolds?

I don't have much time to write a full solution but i would think of excluding the conjugate points of a point p which should be a zero set an then looking at the exponential map of p as a map. And yes every Integral on a complete Manifold can be transferred to a euclidean integral. Hope it helps

thank you,i got it.you are my god!

This was asked and answered a number of times....

Sorry, I haven't been studying Riemannian geometry for long. Can you provide me with a link to this question? Thank you very much.

@Timmathy: Actually, you have to exclude all of the cut points, not just the conjugate points. But it's true that for any point $p\in M$, Riemannian normal coordinates centered at $p$ provide a coordinate chart on the complement of the cut locus, which has measure zero. This follows from Theorem 10.23 in my Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds (2nd ed.).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322027/how-much-of-an-n-dimensional-manifold-can-we-embed-into-mathbbrn/677158#677158

@Jack Lee:
Hello, Mr. Lee,thank you for your correction.I have read your book,in fact,it's Theorem 10.34,but in the second to last line of the first paragraph of the proof,there is exp_p(t_cut (p,v)),i think it should be exp_p(t_cut (p,v)v),exponential mapping should apply to a tangent vector rather than a number.

@ZeShanHongHong: You're right, I should have said Theorem 10.34. And you're right about the incorrect exponential -- that's already in my online correction list.
