# How much of a manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Is it true that for every connected $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, I can remove a closed subset $Z$ of measure zero, such that the the remains $M \setminus Z$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, or at least an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Can I additionally require $Z$ to be a codimension-$1$ submanifold?

Comment: is it related?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11769/do-all-manifolds-have-a-densely-defined-chart

Comment: What about $S^1\times S^1$?